# Can I get the second largest value of a SUM() of rows (using COUNT())?

Tags: mysql, sql

I found separate answers for these questions on this site, but I want to know if these can be combined into one query.

I have a table FollowsCourse which contains CourseID's and StudentID's. I'd like to get the amount of students by calculating the sum of rows of StudentID's per CourseID and then get the second largest value of the resulting output.

I haven't got a clue on where to start, so help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Excuse me for not adding code or desired results. I'll try to clarify!

When asking the question I forgot to add that I won't be using LIMIT (and it's optional parameter OFFSET)

The desired results would be:

```
    Example Table FollowsCourse
    | StudentID | CourseID |
    |     1     |    1     |
    |     2     |    1     |
    |     3     |    2     |
    |     4     |    2     |
    |     5     |    2     |
    |     6     |    1     |
    |     7     |    1     |
    |     8     |    3     |

    result:
    | CourseID | Sum of Count |
    |    1     |     4        |
    |    2     |     3        |
    |    3     |     1        |
```

Then somehow i would need to get CourseID with the second largest Sum of Count (So in this case that'd be CourseID 2.

**PS** I don't have a lot of experience with asking questions so thanks for pointing out that I should add more info about my question.

Comment: A good place to start is to provide sample data and desired results *in your question*.  This helps both you and others understand what you are doing.

Comment: Order the query `ASC` (ASCENDING ) and `LIMIT 1,1` (First 1 is the offset - starting from 0, the second 1 is the number of rows)

Comment: I think "SELECT CourseID, count(CourseID) GROUP BY CourseID ORDER BY count(CourseID) DESC" should give you a list where each row containts course and how many students per course, ordered from highest to lowest per course, and then you would just go through the list and grab the second result for second highest.  I hesitate to post it as an answer though since I tend to make some small mistakes when writing SQL without being able to test it.

Answer (score 1):

As Alon [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan) you need to use LIMIT 1,1. Of course you also need to group by and count.

```
SELECT courseid, 
       Count(studentid) 
FROM   followscourse 
GROUP  BY courseid 
ORDER  BY Count(studentid) DESC 
LIMIT  1, 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d74d/2)

You could also do this by using a rownumber technique but it's much more complicated and is typically only used for [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problems

```
SELECT 
    courseid,
    kount
FROM

     ( SELECT     @num := @num + 1 AS row_number, 
                 courseid,
                 kount

      FROM       ( 
                          SELECT   courseid, 
                                   Count(studentid) kount
                          FROM     followscourse 
                          GROUP BY courseid 
                          ORDER BY Count(studentid) DESC ) AS data 
      CROSS JOIN 
                 ( 
                        SELECT @num := 0 ) rn ) as t
WHERE
  row_number = 2
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d74d/14)

Comment: As you'll see in my edit of the question, I need an answer that doesn't use the LIMIT parameter. Thanks for trying to help though. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use limit